# JavaScript/PHP SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, syntax-error, runtime-error

I am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error when running the line below (which returns a json formatted file from my PHP to my javascript).

```
var moredata = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode(find_detailed_forecast()); ?>");
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. If I edit the line to remove the parentheses or add a '' pair, then I get a "Not Found The requested URL /[object Object] was not found on this server." When I look at the console, the php echo code is running correctly, so I get a JSON.parse(""long string here""). Not sure what is exactly wrong with my javascript and any help would be much appreciated. If it matters, my php, javascript, and html code are all in the same file.

Edit: The code looks like below on execution (its a really long file so I wasn't sure if I should copy paste the entire thing):

```
var moredata = JSON.parse(""{\"latitude\":999.123456,\"longitude\":-999.123456,\"timezone\":\"America\/New_York\",\"currently\":{ .... }"\n"");
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the rendered Javascript too, so we can see what gets echoed?

Comment: You should remove the quotes `"` because `json_encode` adds its own: `JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(find_detailed_forecast()); ?>);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Does the edit above help?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I tried that, but then I get a "Not Found The requested URL /[object Object] was not found on this server." error. I'm not sure which error I should be attempting to find a solution to, as I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse outputs data with double quotes, so you have to use single quotes.

```
var moredata = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(find_detailed_forecast()); ?>');
```